# Error while feeding images to TensorFlow graph

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, grayscale

I am attempting to load some images into a `TensorFlow` graph which are `RGB`, however I would like the graph to transform them to grayscale before processing.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 1], name='x')

gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x, name='grayscale')
```

However I am getting the error

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (250, 32, 32, 3) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 1)'
```

I exported the `notebook` with the error and uploaded it to [Github](https://github.com/autojazari/gtsd-errors/blob/master/compact-solution.md) as an `md` file for completness and brevity.

I realise the error is because the `x_batch` is in RGB shape.

However I thought `TensorFlow` would do the conversion automatically.

Since [tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/image.html#rgb_to_grayscale) wraps the inputs, shouldn't `TF` do the `grayscaling` as part of the session?

Or have I missunderstood how that works?

Comment: If you want to feed in RGB images you need to have a placeholder with shape `[None, 32, 32, 3]`. Then the grayscaling can happen.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot so tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale will do the grayscaling without any further code? How can I ensure gray images are the ones being processed?

Comment: So if you feed RGB images to your placeholder, and then apply `gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)`, the output will be of shape `[None, 32, 32, 1]` and will contain the gray images. You can check the shape of `gray` if you want to be sure.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot - could you promote you comment to an answer?  Thanks!

Comment: @dga : Done. Are you trying to clean up the tensorflow tag?

Comment: Yeah.  Thank you. :)  There was an HN thread griping about our unanswered rate, and there turn out to be a lot of really good answers in the comments, so I figured I'd do a pass.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`tf.image.rgb_to_graycale`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale) expects an input tensor with its last dimension having size 3. For instance a batch of images of shape `(250, 32, 32, 3)` in your case, or it could be a single image of shape `(32, 32, 3)`.

If you want to feed RGB images and immediately process them to grayscale, you can do:

```py
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 3])
gray_images = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(images)  # has shape (None, 32, 32, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you wan to load an RGB image for RGB2grayscale conversion but in placeholder

> x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 1], name='x')

x is defined to have a single dimension, change 1 to 3, error will be removed.